# PEFT LLM model loading is using all available RAM when connected to a GPU on Google Colab?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory, fine-tuning, peft

I am getting the `all available RAM has been used` error when running the following code (I haven't actually performed any fine-tuning as of yet here):

```
model_path = 'openlm-research/open_llama_3b_v2'
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, load_in_8bit=True, 
                                         device_map = 'auto', 
                                         )

#Pass in a prompt and infer with the model
prompt = 'Q: Create a detailed description for the following product: Corelogic Smooth Mouse, belonging to category: Optical Mouse\nA:'
input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

generation_output = model.generate(
input_ids=input_ids, max_new_tokens=128
)

print(tokenizer.decode(generation_output[0]))
```

I've tried setting `load_in_8bit = False` and have tried commenting out the 'device_map' argument. All of these have still resulted in the same Runtime crash.

I have also tried using both a standard GPU and a T4 GPU on colab. Could it be that I have to get Colab Pro to proceed? A friend of mine has performed PEFT using standard colab and he's been fine (though obviously he has been using different configurations etc).

How can I resolve this?